# Legendre Symbol by Fermat's little theorem.

Tags: quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

[image: Question]

My work:

[image]

How do continue with part $b$, I'm so confused.

Comment: ty for formatting

Comment: $g^k\equiv1\mod p\implies p-1$ divides $k$ is false (counter-example: $2^3\equiv1\mod7$).

Comment: @Bern, you're overlooking that $g$ is to be a generator for the multiplicative group.

Comment: It was not in the hypotheses: a generator of $\mathbf Z_p$ is not the same  as a generator of $\mathbf Z_p^\times$.

Comment: @Bern, I think it's clear from the context that we're talking about multiplication, not addition. After all, additively, 1 is a generator, but $g=1$ makes no sense at all in (c).

Answer (score 0):

All elements of $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ satisfy the equation $x^{p-1}=(x^q)^2\equiv=1\mod p,\;$ i.e. $\;x^q\equiv 1$ or $x^q\equiv-1$. Now, all squares satisfy $x^q\equiv1$ by *Lil' Fermat*, and there are $q$ of them.As there can't be more than $q$ solutions to this equation, any element $c$ satisfying $c^q\equiv 1$ *is* a square.